# Excel, find position in array based on two criteria?

Tags: excel-formula

Strugling with this formula:

[image]

I tried to combine INDEX and MATCH but no result....

Comment: please [edit] the post to include the index/match you tried.

Comment: `=INDEX($B$15:$N$17,MATCH(A1,$A$15:$A$17,0),MATCH(D2,$B$14:$M$14,0))` should do it.  If it does not work then the data is a mismatch on the dates, one is text that looks like a date and the other are true dates.

Comment: Thank you very much Scott for your quick help. I understand the formula, I also check the dates and they are both in the right format. Still get an #N/A...

Comment: In your picture A1 has `Engineering Management` and the lookup row has `Engineering` they are not the same

Comment: CORRECTION: It works!! Please post the answer so I can mark as resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index has a row and a column criteria.  We can use 2 matches to return each individually:

```
=INDEX($B$15:$N$17,MATCH(A1,$A$15:$A$17,0),MATCH(D2,$B$14:$M$14,0))
```

Comment: In regards to 'repeating' the range `$A$A14:$N$21`, could the following be simplified `=INDEX($A$14:$N$21,MATCH($A$1,INDEX($A$14:$N$21,0,1),0),MATCH($D$2,INDEX($A$14:$N$21,1,0),0))`?